# Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined in React-Hooks

Tags: reactjs, properties, react-router, react-hooks, location

It worked well before.

But it doesn't work now.

What's the reason?

What should I do?

Unable to read location prop.

Added withRouter to header code,

Then this time there was an error in FriendsHeader.

This is my FriendsHeader code

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Container } from "../BaseLabel";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const FriendstHeader = ({ location: { pathname } }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <FriendContainer>
            <Icons>
              {
                <Links to="/setting">
                  <div current={pathname === "/setting"}>
                    <img src={Cog} width="18px" height="18px" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </Links>
              }
            </Icons>
      </FriendContainer>
    </>
  );
};
export default withRouter(FriendstHeader);
```

This React Router code

```
import React from "react";
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default () => (
  <Router>
    <>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Friends} />
        <Route path="/chats" component={Chats} />
        <Route path="/shap" component={Shap} />
        <Route path="/more" component={More} />
        <Route path="/setting" component={Setting} />
        <Route path="/covid19" component={Covid19} />
        <Route path="/kakaotv" component={KakaoTV} />
        <Route path="/fun" component={Fun} />
        <Route path="/entertain" component={Entertain} />
        <Route path="/sports" component={Sports} />
        <Route path="/openchats" component={OpenChat} />
        <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
      </Switch>
      <Navgation />
    </>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: You are not passing any "location" prop to your Header component, aren't you trying to use useLocation hook instead?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-hooks-of-react-router/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how it ever worked, but you need to either pass the router location in as a prop, or use `withRouter` when exporting your Header component, e.g. in your Header component file have

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

then when exporting:

```
export default withRouter(Header);
```

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Added withRouter to header code,

Then this time there was an error in FriendsHeader. 
This code has withRouter.

Comment: @eeezkim you have a typo, you have  `loaction`. It should be `location`

Comment: Thank you :) soooo much